# Movie about a ghost with blue hands

Tags: story-identification, horror, ghost

I remember watching an Asian horror movie (possibly from Hong Kong?) some time between 2010 and now. It was not older than 5 years by that time, I think.

The movie repeatedly featured a ghost that appeared as a young woman whose arms were noticeably dark blue from the elbows down. The revelation in the end was that the woman was one of many workers in an underground sweatshop (for dyeing fabrics or something - hence the blue arms) who overheard a secret conversation between the owners of said sweatshop, was discovered, and murdered by getting an axe smashed into her head.

At least a few of these aspects are probably misremembered, because my otherwise quite reliable google-fu does not seem to help here.

Comment: *They Wait*, perhaps?

Comment: Two by two, hands of blue.

Comment: @Obie2.0: Well, no, not [that one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefly_(TV_series)).

Comment: @Obie2.0: It is, going to accept that answer. My comment was referring to "two by two, hands of blue", which is how I think the two doctors that experimented on Firefly's River Tam were referred to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Could this be *[They Wait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/They_Wait)*?

[image]

Here is the ghost, a woman with blue-stained arms:

[image]

According to [a review](http://www.eatmybrains.com/showreview.php?id=425):

> When the inquisitive young Sam starts exploring in Uncle Raymond’s **old
>   factory**, he encounters the ghost of a Chinese girl **who worked there
>   half a century ago.** These experiences send Sam into a somnambulic
>   state, which is when he starts creeping us out by saying stuff like,
>   “There is a lot of work to be done”, eventually falling into a coma.
>   Have the spirits taken him? It would certainly appear so, and his mum
>   has only until the following morning (when Ghost Month ends) to rescue
>   his soul.

This certainly fits with the sweatshop angle.

Comment: That's the one. So, the point I was missing was that it was a Canadian movie, while featuring many Asian characters.

Comment: Not to forget that the title is incredibly nondescript and wouldn't have caught my attention in a listing of horror films ;)

Comment: @O.RMapper that is what your friendly neighnorhood stack exchange is for. :)